# lookup with LIKE equivalent in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nosql

I have this code in Postresql and i want to write the same in MongoDB:

```
SELECT
   u.full_name,
   u.phone_number,
   e.full_name,
   e.phone_number
FROM
   client u
   INNER JOIN employee e ON (
       u.phone_number LIKE '%22%'
       AND e.phone_number LIKE '%22%'
   );
```

I know that i can use **lookup** as join equivalent, like:

```
db.client.aggregate({
$lookup:
    {
        from: "employee",
        localField: "client_id",
        foreignField : "_id",
        as: "result"
    }
})
```

and **Like** separately is looks like this:

```
db.client.find({phone_number: /55/})
```

How can I do **join** and **like** equivalents together? I want to join collections by condition, that clients and employee should have for example digits 55 intheir field phone_number
// Upd:
Documents of **client** collection look like this:
client

```
name:'Thomas Smith',
    card_type:'Gold',
    card_term: new Date("2015-05-03"),
    gender:'male',
    password:'dsfsfds',
    phone_number:'494666027570'
    }
....
```

employee:

```
{
    name:'Patrick Manson',
    employee_datebirth: new Date("1986-05-08"),
    employment_start:'2014-12-06',
    gender:'male',
    paycheck:800,
    phone_number:'497185035712',
    position:'bodyweight-trainer'
    },{
....
```

Comment: Can you please give sample docs from these two collections & also required output..

Comment: What is the server version?

Comment: @srinivasy added. Required output is all fields of client and employee together, or just client name, phone number and employee name with phone number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other valid solution is use `$regexMatch` (v>=4.2) or `$regex` operator

```
db.client.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "employee",
      let: {
        c_phone_number: "$phone_number"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: {
            tmp: "$$c_phone_number"
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            phone_number: {
              $regex: ".*55.*"
            },
            tmp: {
              $regex: ".*55.*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            tmp: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "result"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "result.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5wcdxPc-609)

**Note:** As we want `inner join`, but `$lookup` is `left outer join`, we need to add extra `$match` condition.

Comment: "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$regexMatch'",

Comment: @Andrew Are you on mongodb version `<4.2`

Comment: @ambianBeing yes, 4.0.14. I'll try then update version.

Comment: Okay! `$regexMatch` is only available since version `4.2` and above. Updating the db should do it. Although the previous [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) operator can also be used in the `$match` stage.

Comment: @ambianBeing, @Andrew check it again. We can get desired result without `$regexMatch`